# I have a deep subactivity being called (for no reason) after I press Back all the way to first menu

Tags: android-activity

I have Main activity with ListView.

Clicking on a list item  starts activity B with a button.

Clicking on a button starts an activity C with a list view.

Clicking on a list item starts activity D with readonly text view.

All good so far.

I click Back many times to get back to the main activity.

Then, out of nowhere, activity C's createBundle is called by some class
Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity,Bundle), and this causes activity C to
show up.

I tried using startActivityForResult and onActivityResult to see if it would make a 
difference. Nope. Still happens.

I also happens if I subsitite activity C with a simple text view activity called Z.
Z gets shown after I back up to the main activity.

Anyone ever see this?

Why is a deep sub activity being called when the topmost activity is reached (which doesn't call this activity) ?

Comment: Do you have a question besides "Anyone ever see this?"?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by setting breakpoints everywhere.

My Activity B has a button, which is used to launch activity C.

Instead of an ONClickListener, I put on OnTouchListener on the button.

When I click on the button, the on touch listener invoked activity C . This is fine.

However, from activity D, if I press BACK many times to get to the main activity menu...
something is sending a touch event to the button of activity B (even though I am on the main activity) , and this causes a call to activity C.

Not intuitive to notice at all... for a newbie.

I hope this helps someone.